# How to create different membership based site in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: php, membership

i created one registration form with email verification and log in form with all the security. now i want to add monthly paid membership structure in it. also with free trial for 30 days. i can't understand the logic to implement this thing. it will be great if some one give me proper direction to achieve it.

this is main requirement

1st user can use trial membership for 30 days.
2nd is monthly membership fees, user can start anytime by paying monthly fees and also he can select it when he register - free or monthly fees.

my system is in php and created on codeigniter framework. but i suppose you dont worry on that, i want to just know logic or understanding of this thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you gonna use paypal for paid membership? if so things would be easier:
0.Show him the tryial choice **and** the direct pay on the entrance.If he choses 30 days trial then
1.register him  in database user table with the date of user registration or create a table of  trials and put in it users and their registration date
2.When the user logs in back, check whether 30 days have expired if yes let him in if no ask him to pays fee->direct him to paypal paid membership
In this process you don't have to ask for him paying directly **or** 30days trial, let him do one thing at a time.Give him alternatives on the site. Show him that he can chose. I think this will give you an Idea.

Comment: yes that was what i was thinking to do. but when i got that from my client that there will be 4 types of membership in system with different access criteria. so when user goes for registration, he must select one of them - like free, broze, silver and gold. also i have to implement paypal with that. so if user select free than it directly register and if selects any other than go to paypal, make payment and than return to site. also i have to track them monthly pay for their membership too.

Comment: Why can't you just register them and give them free staffs and offer them 30 days trials insinde. For being able to offer more than two offers you need to register different offer payement options on paypal like silver, gold,..Then you direct each choice to the right paypal button. I actually don't see where is your problem maybe you should explain a little more.